# Intercom push notifications in swift

Tags: ios, swift, intercom, intercom-ios

I am trying to register an app for intercoms push notifications. They have instructions here: https://docs.intercom.io/Install-on-your-mobile-product/enabling-push-notifications-with-intercom-for-ios

They give this code in obj c, but my app is in swift and this looks like gibberish to me:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {    
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){ // iOS 8 (User notifications)
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:
         [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
          (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
           UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
           UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)
                                           categories:nil]];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else { // iOS 7 (Remote notifications)
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationType)
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
          UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
          UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
}
```

Could someone explain how to do this process in swift?

Comment: Just search Google for "swift registerForRemoteNotifications" there are many examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code works on Xcode 7.1 by using the new availability feature added to Swift 2

```
if #available(iOS 8, *) {
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType(rawValue: UIUserNotificationType.Badge.rawValue |
                UIUserNotificationType.Sound.rawValue |
                UIUserNotificationType.Alert.rawValue),
            categories: nil))
} else {
    application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(
        UIRemoteNotificationType(rawValue: UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge.rawValue |
        UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert.rawValue |
        UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound.rawValue))
}
```

Comment: Updated the code, you would need to use availability feature in Xcode 7 if you wanna use platform specific code